# Create request in JIRA from Jenkins

Tags: rest, http, curl, jenkins, jira

I want to use the REST API of JIRA to create issue. I found the following:
https://developer.atlassian.com/jiradev/jira-apis/jira-rest-apis

The Jenkins ad JIRA are installed on windows so I cant use curl.

I am able to make http request from browser and create issues in JIRA. But not sure how to do same from Jenkins. Jenkins has a HTTP request plugin, but it doesn't have a data fields to make a proper POST call.

Please suggest some alternatives or a way to fix the above scenarios.

Comment: I'm sorry I don't understand the issue. You should be able to make a proper POST with the HTTP request plugin. What exactly is the problem?

Comment: @jjhavokk, The POST in Jenkins http plugin doesn't have a section for response data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jenkins has https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/JIRA+Plugin which can handle issue creating:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, let me give it a shot

Comment: this plugin creates the issue only when the build fails, doesn't it ?